# Qt HTML5 Application with a CMS

Tags: html, qt, joomla

I want to make a HTML5 Application using Qt and QWebKit.  The HTML5 application will require some sort of authentication (like logging into the application to access data).  I know the QWebkit can display contents from an HTML file or a URL (that the point of QWebKit :D ), but for writing these different components (authentication, content, etc...) takes time and is already done in some way or another.

Can I use some sort of CMS like Joomla, to display the HTML5 Application, so that I can use the different features (components, plugins, modules, WYSIWIG, etc.. ) to build my Application?  Or is there some better way of achieving this?

Comment: It is strange that you leave so many of your questions without a selected answer even when many people try to help you. You do not provide any critics either.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can easily build a HTML5 web app with Joomla. Most of the things you have mentioned here is built into Joomla, Only you will have to customize few things here and there. Please refer this link as well. [How to build a Joomla Template HTML5](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-build-a-joomla-template-start-to-finish/)